# Confounding vs. effect modification in 2x2 tables

Tags: odds-ratio, confounding

I'm doing a statistics course at the moment and have a quick question about effect modification and confounding, and working out which is which in 2x2 tables in a case-control stud.

I have three categorical variables; drug use (current, ex, never), cancer (present, not present), and vitamin use (taking regularly, not taking).

I have been supplied with three 2x2 tables. Each table evaluates the relationship between cancer and vitamin use, with each table stratified by drug use. Drug use is a known cause of cancer, and so has to be included as a potential confounder.

I've been looking it up and I found this which I only partially understand:
"In the presence of confounding, the association between exposure and disease is the same, or similar, at each level of the third variable, but the crude and adjusted OR /RR differ.

In contrast, when effect modification is present, the association between each exposure and outcome is different for different strata. The difference can be in direction or magnitude."

In this instance I take it that the:

- Crude odds ratio is the relationship between vitamin use and cancer for all patients.
- Stratified odds ratio is the relationship between vitamin use and cancer, for each type level of drug use.

What is the adjusted odds ratio in this scenario? What other analyses do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.